# Compile Apache APR on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, awk, apr

The end result is I am trying to compile something that requires the APR from Apache on Windows.

Edit:  Tried Visual Studio command line tools for VS2013 & VS2014.
       Link for SVN checkout shows 404: http://apr.apache.org/anonsvn.txt

so...

From this link http://apr.apache.org/compiling_win32.html I have downloaded the three files.  I unzipped them and renames them as the directory structure suggested.

C:\work\apr\
C:\work\apr-iconv\
C:\work\apr-util\

Moved to the apr-util directory and ran the following make command and received the following errors.

Note there is the comment about "Current versions of APR do not need awk..." but the link does not work, does it matter?

Anybody have any luck compiling this, do I need other lib/include/objects?

nmake -f Makefile.win buildall checkall installall clean

Received the following errors:

```
<clip>
rc.exe /l 0x409 /fo".\Release\libapriconv.res" /i "./include" /i "../apr/include" /d "NDEBUG" /d "API_VERSION_ONLY" .\libapriconv.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.3.9600.17336
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

link.exe @C:\Users\JOHNAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nm390A.tmp
Creating library .\Release\libapriconv-1.lib and object .\Release\libapriconv-1.exp
    if exist .\Release\libapriconv-1.dll.manifest mt.exe -manifest .\Release\libapriconv-1.dll.manifest -outputresource:.\Release\libapriconv-1.dll;2
    echo Helper for Post-build step > ".\Release\postbld.dep"
    cd ccs
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -nologo -f Makefile.win all  BUILD_MODE="Win32 Release" BIND_MODE=shared adobe-stdenc.c
Creating library ..\Release\iconv\adobe-stdenc.lib and object ..\Release\iconv\adobe-stdenc.exp
adobe-stdenc.obj : error LNK2011: precompiled object not linked in; image may not run
..\Release\iconv\adobe-stdenc.so : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late, but here is how I fixed it.

In the build\modules.mk.win makefile change line 221 from

```
$(SILENT)link $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $*.obj $(API_LIBS) /out:$@ \
```

To

```
$(SILENT)link $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $*.obj $(MODRES).obj $(API_LIBS) /out:$@ \
```

The shared library target will now read:

```
.c{$(OUTPUT_DIR)}.so:
$(SILENT)cl $(ALL_CFLAGS) /Fo$*.obj /Yuiconv.h /c $<
$(SILENT)link $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $*.obj $(MODRES).obj $(API_LIBS) /out:$@ \
    /base:@"..\build\BaseAddr.ref",$(@F)
$(SILENT)if exist $@.manifest \
    $(SILENT)mt -nologo -manifest $@.manifest -outputresource:$@;2 \
    & del "$@.manifest"
$(SILENT)del "$*.exp" & del "$*.lib"
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/mkhon/01a1536b01e0065ae799

Answer (score 2):

From the apache-apr project site under heading:

> Developer Studio Workspace/Microsoft Development Environment IDE Build::
>
> Open the apr-util/aprutil.dsw workspace, and choose either aprutil or libaprutil (for static or dynamic libraries) with the Release or Debug build as the Active Project. aprutil.dsw causes all related projects to be built.

Maybe you overlooked this statement : *choose either aprutil or libaprutil as the Active Project*...

Then build the active project.